# Statistics, least square method

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, least-squares

I am having problems with an exercise. I have some observations of the random variable $Y$:
$0.17, 0.06, 1.76, 3.41, 11.68, 1.86, 1.27, 0.00, 0.04,$ and $2.10$.

I know that $Y = X^2$ and that $X \sim \mathrm{N}(\mu, 1)$.
Now I am supposed to estimate $\mu$ using the least square method.

I use the formula:

$$Q(\mu) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} (x_i - \mu)^.2$$

My solution is that since $Y = X^2 \Leftrightarrow X = \sqrt{Y}$, then using the formula I have

$$Q(\mu) = \sum_{i=1}^{10} (\sqrt{y_i} - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{10} (\sqrt{y_i}^2 - 2 \mu \sum_{i=1}^{10} \sqrt{y_i} + \sum_{i=1}^{10} \mu^2$$

which gives me

$$(0.17 + 0.06 +\cdots +2.10)-2\mu (\sqrt{0.17}+\sqrt{0.06}+\cdots+\sqrt{2.10}) + 10\mu^2$$ and

$$Q'(\mu) = 20\mu - 2(\sqrt{0.17}+\sqrt{0.06}+\cdots+\sqrt{2.10}).$$

Setting this to zero (to minimize) gives me

$$\mu = 2(\sqrt{0.17}+\sqrt{0.06}+\cdots+\sqrt{2.10})/20 = 1.13880\ldots$$

However, the answer should be 1.111. Can you spot any obvious mistakes? I feel like I have double checked this so many times now and I still think it looks alright, so the only conclusion I can draw is that I have missed something important about how to use this method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to maximize $Q(u)$? It's the least square method, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I will edit the question.

Comment: @luka5z : It's not $u$; it's $\mu$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The problem is not clearly formulated (at least in a common sense). In principle, least square method is used to estimate the coefficients of an unknown functional relationship, for example, you can use LS to estimate $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ in $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \epsilon$. If you already know $Y = X^2$, what is the point? Also, you don't need distributional assumptions in LS setting.

Comment: Based on the information you provided, a more natural estimation method is the maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: @Solitary : I think you are mistaken.  I will post an answer that will explain that. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I'm sure it is but the purpose of this exercise is to practise using the LS-method to estimate the mean, and it kind of bugs me that I haven't been able to solve it yet. :)

Comment: Please refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) wiki page for a standard least squares method context. Personally, I am unconvinced that your problem is a typical LS problem.

Comment: @Solitary: Maybe my answer below will convince you. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael, I know... just quoted OP

Comment: @luka5z : No, you didn't.  The OP wrote $Q(\mu)$, not $Q(u)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Nevermind, it's obvious what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\bar x =(x_1+\cdots+x_n)/n$ be the sample mean.  Then
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^n ((x_i-\bar x) + (\bar x - \mu))^2 \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \Big( (x_i-\bar x)^2 + 2(x_i-\bar x)(\bar x-\mu) + (\bar x - \mu)^2) \\[10pt]
& = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)^2 \right) + \left( 2 (\bar x - \mu) \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)}_\text{This sum is 0.} \right) + n(\bar x - \mu)^2 \\[10pt]
& = n(\bar x - \mu)^2 + (\text{something not depending on }\mu).
\end{align}
This first expression in the display above --- the sum of squares of deviations from $\mu$ --- is thus shown to be equal to the last expression, an increasing function of the square of the absolute difference between the population mean $\mu$ and the sample mean $\bar x$.  The last expression is clearly minimized by $\mu=\bar x$; therefore the sample mean $\bar x$ is the least squares estimator of the population mean $\mu$.  And you appear to have computed it correctly.

Let us note, however, that
$$
\operatorname{E} Y = \operatorname{E}(X^2) = \Big(\operatorname{E} X\Big)^2 + \operatorname{var}(X) = \mu^2 + 1.
$$
The sample mean of the $Y$ values, which is the least-squares estimator of the population mean of $Y$, is $2.235$.  So if we then solve $\mu^2+1=2.235$ for $\mu$, we get about $1.111306$, apparently coinciding with what you say is the correct value.

However, either way, the maximum-likelihood estimate of $\mu$ is just what you got, the mean of the $X$ values.

Comment: I would say it is a method of moments estimation instead of least squares estimation. My main point is, given the information/setting provided, the problem should not be termed as a Least Squares problem, don't you agree with me?

Comment: @Solitary : Least squares coincides with maximum likelihood for i.i.d. normally distributed observations.  For the $Y$ values above, least squares coincides with method-of-moments estimation, not with maximum likelihood.  The maximum-likelihood estimate of $\mu$ is the mean of the observed $X$ values regardless of whether it's based on the observed $X$ values or the observed $Y$ values. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Please start teaching at my school. That was such a pedagogical and clear answer. Thank you!

Comment: @m.bing : Thank you; I'm glad you liked it.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I didn't say MLE coincides with LSE in this problem. Maybe you still didn't get my point. My points are: (1) The problem setting (to me) is not a standard LSE problem. (2) We could use MLE instead of LSE to estimate $\mu$ to get a more efficient estimate, given we had the distributional form of $X$. In fact, in your solution you didn't use $X$ is normally distributed but just use its moments condition. That you call the sample mean as a LSE of $\mu$ is rarely heard of (although mathematically it makes sense).

Comment: As I pointed out in my previous comment to OP, the standard setting that the least squares method applies to probably should be like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Problem_statement).

Comment: @Solitary : I am the one who said maximum likelihood coincides with least squares when the observations are i.i.d. normal. Since they coincide, neither will give more accurate estimates than the other.  It is true that I didn't use the assumption of normality to derive the least-squares estimator, nor did I derive the maximum-likelihood estimator.  That is because I was trying to do least-squares estimation, not maximum-likelihood estimation.  That the sample mean is the least-squares estimator of the population mean is sometimes posed as an exercise in textbooks. ${}\qquad{}$